# C++ template specialisation friend iterator error: invalid use of incomplete type

Tags: c++, iterator, friend, template-specialization

For a project I'm working at, I've created a C++ library that encapsulates data structures. For each data structure, I've created custom iterators to navigate through data elegantly. Everything went fine until I've tried template specialization on those classes, when I stumbled upon this build error: 
**error: invalid use of incomplete type.**

I've banged my head for more than a week on this and found nothing helpful on the net, so I thought maybe some of you can help me with this...

The whole problem simplified:

```
template<typename T>
class DataStructureIterator;
// OK
template<typename T>
class DataStructure {
    friend class DataStructureIterator<T>;
    public:
        typedef DataStructureIterator<T> iterator;

        ...

        iterator begin() {
            return iterator(this);
        }

        iterator end(){
            return iterator(count);
        }

};
// ERROR: "Invalid use of incomplete type" (on ANY specialization attempt)
template<>
class DataStructure<double> {
    friend class DataStructureIterator<double>;
    public:
        typedef DataStructureIterator<double> iterator;

        ...

        iterator begin() {
            return iterator(this);
        }

        iterator end(){
            return iterator(count);
        }

};

template<typename T>
class DataStructureIterator { ... }
```

Example:

```
template<typename T>
struct DoublyLinkedListEntry {
    T value;
    DoublyLinkedListEntry* next;
    DoublyLinkedListEntry* previous;
};

template<typename T>
class DoublyLinkedListIterator;

template<typename T>
class DoublyLinkedList {
    friend class DoublyLinkedListIterator<T>;
    public:
        typedef DoublyLinkedListIterator<T> iterator;

        DoublyLinkedList() {
            head = nullptr;
            tail = nullptr;
            count = 0;
        }

        ~DoublyLinkedList() {
            empty();
        }

        void add(const T& value) {
            DoublyLinkedListEntry<T>* element = new DoublyLinkedListEntry<T>;
            element->value = value;
            element->next = nullptr;
            element->previous = tail;
            if(head==nullptr) {
                head = element;
            } else {
                tail->next = element;
            }
            tail = element;
            ++ count;
        }

        iterator begin() {
            return iterator(this);
        }

        iterator end(){
            return iterator(count);
        }
    private:
        void empty(){
            DoublyLinkedListEntry<T>* temp = head;
            DoublyLinkedListEntry<T>* del = temp;
            while(del != nullptr) {
                temp = temp->next;
                delete del;
                del = temp;
            }
        }

        DoublyLinkedListEntry<T>* head;
        DoublyLinkedListEntry<T>* tail;
        std::size_t count;
};

template<>
class DoublyLinkedList<double> {
    friend class DoublyLinkedListIterator<double>;
    public:
        typedef DoublyLinkedListIterator<double> iterator;

        DoublyLinkedList() {
            head = nullptr;
            tail = nullptr;
            count = 0;
        }

        ~DoublyLinkedList() {
            empty();
        }

        void add(double& value) {
            DoublyLinkedListEntry<double>* element = new DoublyLinkedListEntry<double>;
            element->value = value;
            element->next = nullptr;
            element->previous = tail;
            if(head==nullptr) {
                head = element;
            } else {
                tail->next = element;
            }
            tail = element;
            ++ count;
        }

        iterator begin() {
            return iterator(this);
        }

        iterator end(){
            return iterator(count);
        }
    private:
        void empty(){
            DoublyLinkedListEntry<double>* temp = head;
            DoublyLinkedListEntry<double>* del = temp;
            while(del != nullptr) {
                temp = temp->next;
                delete del;
                del = temp;
            }
        }

        DoublyLinkedListEntry<double>* head;
        DoublyLinkedListEntry<double>* tail;
        std::size_t count;
};

template<typename T>
class DoublyLinkedListIterator {
    public:
        DoublyLinkedListIterator(){
            list = nullptr;
            current_item = nullptr;
            offset = 0;
        }

        DoublyLinkedListIterator(DoublyLinkedList<T>* list){
            this->list = list;
            current_item = list->head;
            offset = 0;
        }

        DoublyLinkedListIterator(std::size_t total){
            list = nullptr;
            current_item = nullptr;
            offset = total;
        }

        ~DoublyLinkedListIterator(){}

        const T operator*(){
            return current_item->value;
        }

        bool operator!=(const DoublyLinkedListIterator<T>& it) const {
            return offset!=it.offset;
        }

        DoublyLinkedListIterator<T>& operator++(){
            if(current_item!=nullptr) {
                current_item = current_item->next;
            }
            ++offset;
            return *this;
        }

    private:
        DoublyLinkedList<T>* list;
        DoublyLinkedListEntry<T>* current_item;
        std::size_t offset;
};
```

Build error:

```
In file included from ../src/Learning.cpp:11:0:
../src/DoublyLinkedList.h: In member function ‘DoublyLinkedList<double>::iterator DoublyLinkedList<double>::begin()’:
../src/DoublyLinkedList.h:107:20: error: return type ‘DoublyLinkedList<double>::iterator {aka class DoublyLinkedListIterator<double>}’ is incomplete
   iterator begin() {
                    ^
../src/DoublyLinkedList.h:108:24: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘DoublyLinkedList<double>::iterator {aka class DoublyLinkedListIterator<double>}’
    return iterator(this);
                        ^
../src/DoublyLinkedList.h:22:7: error: declaration of ‘DoublyLinkedList<double>::iterator {aka class DoublyLinkedListIterator<double>}’
 class DoublyLinkedListIterator;
       ^
../src/DoublyLinkedList.h: In member function ‘DoublyLinkedList<double>::iterator DoublyLinkedList<double>::end()’:
../src/DoublyLinkedList.h:111:17: error: return type ‘DoublyLinkedList<double>::iterator {aka class DoublyLinkedListIterator<double>}’ is incomplete
   iterator end(){
                 ^
../src/DoublyLinkedList.h:112:25: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘DoublyLinkedList<double>::iterator {aka class DoublyLinkedListIterator<double>}’
    return iterator(count);
                         ^
../src/DoublyLinkedList.h:22:7: error: declaration of ‘DoublyLinkedList<double>::iterator {aka class DoublyLinkedListIterator<double>}’
 class DoublyLinkedListIterator;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear.

`class DoublyLinkedListIterator<double>` is an incomplete type when you try to create instances of the class in the following functions:

```
    iterator begin() {
        return iterator(this);
    }

    iterator end(){
        return iterator(count);
    }
```

You can resolve this using either of the following methods.

1. Move the definition of `template<typename T> class DoublyLinkedListIterator` before the definition of `template<> class DataStructure<double>`.
2. Don't define the above functions inline. Only declare them. Define them after the definition of `template<typename T> class DoublyLinkedListIterator`.

Comment: Used option #2 and everything works perfectly. Thanks a lot!